# Understanding Netty - sending and receiving objects

Tags: netty

Although I spend a couple of hours going through tutorials, I have a hard time understanding Netty. I want to send a couple of different objects between client and server, but I don't know how to do it properly. It seems possible to just serialize an object and to send it like that and on the recieving end it is put together into an object of that class. However, I have read that there could be limitations concerning the size of that object. Also, I don't understand how to handle the channelRead-functions of the handlers, as they are also called when the object is not received in full length. Can I just wait until channelReadComplete is called and put the object back together then?

Since I want a couple of different object with variable length, I also wonder if it is advisable and possible to use ByteBuf instead and somehow read out the first byte that holds the information about the object-type and somehow casts the remaining received bytes in the correct type of object.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

TeaDrinkerJoe

Comment: There is example in the Netty Github for simple transfer of objects you could check that. Also, you could write your own custom encoders and decoders for transferring different kind of objects and handle them separately. But just remember netty can only pass ByteBuf or Fileregion in its channel.  https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/objectecho

Answer (score 1):

You can use a netty `Encoder` to encode or serialize your objects to bytes and write a `Decoder` to decode or deserialize the received bytes. You can have your own serialization and deserialization implementations, but make sure that you can differentiate the objects in a continuous byte stream.